# Whole + Plural Nouns

Tags: grammar, british-english, determiners

On my old Upper-Intermediate Book it's reported that whole plus a plural noun ( for instance whole businesses) means each one.

To be more clear, I write here the explanation the book gives:

"It's possible to say WHole businesses are affected....without the definite article, but this refears to each individual business"

So, my question is:  "Does it mean each business?"    Surfing on the Internet, I saw it is generally explained that it means "entire businesses", meaning many of them but not all of them.

Might you explain it to me?

Comment: *Whole businesses* means *entire businesses*, not just parts of businesses. In the same way *whole families* would mean that every member of the family is included - mother, father and children. *Whole families* is the opposite of *part families* i.e. those that only include some of the family members, but not all.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily even mean 'many of them'. Just two entire businesses out of 300 say might be affected.

Answer (score 3):

***Whole businesses are affected*** does not mean ***All businesses or every business***, but it means that ***some businesses are affected completely.***

> - You use **whole** after **a** to emphasize that you mean *all of    something of a particular kind.*
>
> *We worked on the project for **a whole year**.*
>
> *I drank **a whole pot** of coffee, and I still felt tired.*
>
> - You can also use **whole** like this in front of the **plural** form of a    noun.
>
>   *There were **whole paragraphs** in the article that I didn't
>
>     understand.*
>
> **Be Careful!**
>
> In front of plurals, **whole** does not have the same meaning as
>   **all.** If you say ***'All the buildings have been destroyed'***, you mean that ***every building has been destroyed.*** If you say
>   ***'Whole buildings have been destroyed'***, you mean that ***some buildings have been destroyed completely.***

From (thefreedictionary.com) ***[Collins COBUILD English Usage](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/whole)***.

Answer (score 2):

*Whole businesses* means *entire businesses*, not just parts of businesses.

In the same way *whole families* would mean that every member of the family is included - mother, father and children.

*Whole families* is the opposite of *part families* i.e. those that only include some of the family members, but not all.

Thus *whole businesses* means all parts of each business are included.